# Washington 2.18d, elliptic curves change of variables in characteristic 3

Tags: elliptic-curves, change-of-variable

I got stuck on the Exercise 2.18d in the Book: Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography.
The problem is:

> Show that if $y^2 = x^3 +a_4 x+a_6$ and $y^2 = x^3 +a'_4x^2 + a'_6$ are two elliptic curves (in characteristic 3), then there is a change of variables $ y \mapsto ay , x \mapsto bx +c$, with $a,b \in \overline{K}^{\times}$ and $c \in \overline{K}$, that changes one equation into the other.

My Problem is transforming the $x$ into the $x^2$, I guess you should somehow use that we operate in char 3. Since $(bx +c)^3 = b^3x^3 + c^3$ we can't get our $x^2$ from here.

Edit:
It seems my version of the Book has a spelling mistake and the exercise should be $y² = x³ +a_4x +a⁶$ and $y²=x³ + a'_4x + a'_6$. I use the version "Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography, 2nd Edition, CRC Press, Versiondate:20131121". If someone should stumble on the same problem.

Comment: The coefficients $a_4, a_6$ and $a_4', a_6'$ are related somehow?

Comment: The notation is very confusing, using the term $a_4'x^2$ in the second equation should be agains the will to write it for an elliptic hand... In the first curve we have $a_2=0$, so the $j$-invariant is zero, but in the second curve, $y^2=x^3+a'_4\color{red}{x^2}+a'_6$ if $a'_4\ne 0$...

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I found a online available copy of the book, and it seems my version of the book has a spelling mistake: https://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/~rjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf

Comment: Yes, this solves the issue, it was certainly a typo (in the other edition of the book). Thanks for the link, now i see the notations and the framework, yes, the exercise 2.18 (d) wants to show that in characteristic $3$ two elliptic curves having the $j$-invariant equal to zero are isomorphic over the algebraic closure of the base field. Things are now making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a spelling mistake in the Book. I found an [errata](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Elcw/ECerrata2.pdf) for the Book.

> Show that if $y^2 = x^3 +a_4 x+a_6$ and $y^2 = x^3 +a'_4{\color{red}{x}} + a'_6$ are two elliptic curves (in characteristic 3), then there is a change of variables $ y \mapsto ay , x \mapsto bx +c$, with $a,b \in \overline{K}^{\times}$ and $c \in \overline{K}$, that changes one equation into the other.